# Password update statement does not update

Tags: php

So i'm trying to making a forgot password function. Everything works except the update statement is not updating the password. the token is updated but not the password. Can someone please instruct me as to what i am doing wrong. thanks in advance.

resetPassword.php:

```
<?php
        session_start();
        include '../connection/login-db.php';

        function reset_submit(){
            GLOBAL $db;
            if (isset($_GET['reset']) && $_GET['reset'] == 'true') {
                $password = $_POST['password'];
                $confirmPassword = $_POST['confirmPassword'];
                if ($password == $confirmPassword) {

                $email     = $_SESSION['email'];
                $password  = password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
                $Query     = $db->prepare("UPDATE user SET password, forgotToken) VALUES (?, ?) WHERE email='$email");
                $Query->execute([$password, '']);
                if ($Query) {

                    echo json_encode(['error' => 'success', 'msg' => 'resetSuccess.php']);
                }////close Query///////////
            }////password check match///////////

            }////close reset isset///////////
        }////close reset submit method///////////
        reset_submit();
    ?>
```

Comment: can you be more specific. i'm asking for help.

Comment: He has asked a question and provided his code. I see nothing wrong with that. This is what we are here for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct SQL syntax needs to be like following:

```
UPDATE tutorials_tbl
  SET tutorial_title="Learning JAVA", column2 = "colval2"
  WHERE tutorial_id=3
```

Comment: Thanks much. That worked perfectly I'll be sure to write it down in my journal so i don't forget..